# WCF on IIS and access denied due to Access Control Lists Error

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7, ado.net

I'm writing simple application which is using WCF service application hosted on IIS. Everything is working in VS12 so now I want to put WCF on IIS server. I copied all svc, svc.cs and web.config files to WCFHost folder and in WCFHost/bin/ I put files created by debugger. I configured IIS and when trying to run host in chrome it gives me error:

```
Server Error in '/WCFHost' Application.

Access is denied.

Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. You might not have permission to view the requested resources. 

Error message 401.3: You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied (access denied due to Access Control Lists). Ask the Web server's administrator to give you access to 'C:\Users\MiSiek\Documents\WcfNewsletter_2'.

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

When creating new application on IIS i used my user and pass.

My web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NewsletterEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/NewsletterDAL_EF.csdl|res://*/NewsletterDAL_EF.ssdl|res://*/NewsletterDAL_EF.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Newsletter;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFHost.MessageService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFHost.IMessageService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/WcfServiceLibrary/MessageService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="WCFHost.MailingListService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFHost.IMailingListService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/WcfServiceLibrary/MailingListService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="WCFHost.RecipientService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFHost.IRecipientService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/WcfServiceLibrary/RecipientService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="WCFHost.SenderService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFHost.ISenderService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/WcfServiceLibrary/SenderService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: In IIS you run under the credential of the app (as as in IIS app).  In VS you run under the credentials you are logged in as.  I would put the newsletter in the IIS directory of you asp.net site or application.

Comment: But I run IIS application with my user not default IIS credentials. I changed it in "connect as" settings when i created application in IIS. Is this what You mean? Or should I change something else?

Comment: IIS is running under the account of the application pool.  Did you try to just copy the file to IIS directory of you asp.net application and point to it there?